# Notation for the set of all real spaces of abitrary size

Tags: functions, notation

What is the general notation for a function $f$ that maps a point in $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$f : \mathbb{N} \mapsto ?$

What is ?

Comment: I think that your question it's no clear. You can write how do you like it, for example $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: yes but the output dimension depends on the input so n=1 gets mapped to R^1 and n=2 gets mapped to R^2.

Comment: So... you have an input, I'll call $a$ which is a natural number and you want $a$ to output to a set in $\Bbb R^b$ where $b$ is necessarily equal to $a$?  Letting $Y = \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R^1)\cup \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R^2)\cup \mathcal{P}(\Bbb R^3)\cup\dots$ perhaps you mean to have $f~:~\Bbb N\to Y$.  Note that all we are interested in this part of the notation is the codomain.  We aren't interested in the fact that $f(a)$ must specifically map to a set in $\Bbb R^a$.  That aspect of it can be handled later when we define more specifically $a\mapsto ?$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes $a=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with $f:\Bbb N\to \mathcal P\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb R^n\right)$ and then specify the additional condition that $f(n)\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ for all $n$, *or* you can be arguably a little more obscure and say that $f\in\prod\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal P(\Bbb R^n)$. Personally, I don't know which one to recommend, but probably in general I'd choose the first one.

Comment: the first one sounds great. I just thought there might a common symbol for this.

Comment: and what is the reason i need the $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: You said "a function $f$ that maps a point in $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$", so the codomain must be some kind of power set.

Comment: ah yes thats correct.